# Repeat a rule with a new line of my knowledge base

Tags: prolog

I am having a problem, I have the following line of code:

```
aux(O,LD,LF):-
   line(Id,LE),
   aux(O,LD,Id,1,LE,_,[],LAF),
   LF = (LAF,LE).
```

I want that if LAF is an empty list, to get my next fact

```
line(...)
```

of my knowledge base. I tried this:

```
aux(O,LD,LF):-
   line(Id,LE),
   aux(O,LD,Id,1,LE,_,[],LAF),
   (LAF==[],false),
   LF = (LAF,LE).
```

Shouldn't turning the condition false repeating the process for the next line?

Comment: The use of `false` here will cause backtracking to the prior subclauses of the `aux/3` predicate. Also, `LF = (LAF, LE)` will never occur because of the preceding `false`. The parentheses don't help here, as the `false` will always be encountered.

Comment: `swi-prolog` has [control structures](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,'4.8',swi('/doc/Manual/control.html'))). You can use that to solve your problem. Just place it after then aux() predicate.